# Teradata error Ordered Analytical Function not allowed in group by clause

Tags: teradata

I'm getting the error:

```
Ordered Analytical Function not allowed in group by clause
```

for below query.

```
SELECT 
CC.CASE_ID as CASE_ID,
FIRST_VALUE(CC.CASE_OWN_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID )as    FST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,
FIRST_VALUE(CC.LSTMOD_BY_AGNT_PRFL_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID)as  FST_AGNT_PRFL_NM,
LAST_VALUE(CC.CASE_OWN_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID) as     LST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,
LAST_VALUE(CC.LSTMOD_BY_AGNT_PRFL_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID)  as  LST_AGNT_PRFL_NM,
case when CC.CASE_OWN_NM is not null then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) end as FST_AGNT_EDIT_DTTM,
case when CC.CASE_OWN_NM is not null then MAX(CC.REC_DTTM_PST)  end as LST_AGNT_EDIT_DTTM,
case when CC.CASE_STS_CD='Open'  then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) end as CASE_OPEN_DTTM,
case when CC.CASE_STS_CD in ( 'Closed', 'Auto Closed') then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) end as CASE_CLSE_OR_AUTO_CLSE_DTTM,
count( distinct CC.CASE_OWN_NM) as  CASE_OWN_CHGS_IN_NUM,
--IIF((MAX(CC.CASE_TFR_TO_L2) = 1),'Yes','No')  as ESCL_FL,
LAST_VALUE(CC.ESCL_RSN_TXT)   OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID )as ESCL_RSN_TXT,
LAST_VALUE( CC.ESCL_DTLS_TXT)    OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID ) as ESCL_DTLS_TXT


FROM EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE CC
INNER JOIN EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE_EXTN CCE
ON CC.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY = CCE.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY
INNER JOIN EDW_STAGE_COMN_SRC.STG_CNTCT_CASE_DELTA  DELTA
on CC.CASE_ID = DELTA.CASE_ID
group by 1,2,3,4,5


sample 1
```

Comment: @user3514648..does my solution in your earlier post didn't worked??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teradata Orderer Analytical Function not allowed in group by clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775769/teradata-orderer-analytical-function-not-allowed-in-group-by-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CC.CASE_ID as CASE_ID, CC.FST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,      CC.FST_AGNT_PRFL_NM,
        CC.LST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,        CC.LST_AGNT_PRFL_NM,CC.ESCL_RSN_TXT,CC.ESCL_DTLS_TXT,
        case 
    when CC.CASE_OWN_NM is not null then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) 
end as FST_AGNT_EDIT_DTTM, 
case    
    when CC.CASE_OWN_NM is not null then MAX(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) 
end as LST_AGNT_EDIT_DTTM, 
case    
    when CC.CASE_STS_CD='Open' then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) 
end as CASE_OPEN_DTTM, 
case    
    when CC.CASE_STS_CD in ( 'Closed', 'Auto Closed') then MIN(CC.REC_DTTM_PST) 
end as CASE_CLSE_OR_AUTO_CLSE_DTTM, count( distinct CC.CASE_OWN_NM) as CASE_OWN_CHGS_IN_NUM

FROM    (select FIRST_VALUE(CC.CASE_OWN_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID )as FST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,
        FIRST_VALUE(CC.LSTMOD_BY_AGNT_PRFL_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID)as FST_AGNT_PRFL_NM,
        LAST_VALUE(CC.CASE_OWN_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID) as LST_AGNT_CASE_OWN_NM,
        LAST_VALUE(CC.LSTMOD_BY_AGNT_PRFL_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID) as LST_AGNT_PRFL_NM
        ,LAST_VALUE(CC.ESCL_RSN_TXT) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID )as ESCL_RSN_TXT,
        LAST_VALUE( CC.ESCL_DTLS_TXT) OVER(PARTITION BY CC.CASE_ID ) as ESCL_DTLS_TXT 
        from EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE ) CC INNER JOIN EDW_KATAMARI_T.CNTCT_CASE_EXTN CCE 
    ON CC.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY = CCE.CNTCT_CASE_APND_KEY INNER JOIN EDW_STAGE_COMN_SRC.STG_CNTCT_CASE_DELTA DELTA 
    on CC.CASE_ID = DELTA.CASE_ID 
group by 1,2,3,4,5 ,6,7
sample  1
```